# how to prevent delete and add in all sections - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, push, splice

I have a problem when adding several sections and within each section attempt to add other questions, but these are added in all sections. I hope someone can help.

code here: http://goo.gl/XQas0x

Comment: Please be a bit more specific and add the important parts of your code here on SO, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one questions array is not enough to represent each `items` section.
If you think about it, there must be one array per `item`. You could make `questions` a property of each `item` as NMittal suggests. That will work.

Another approach, if you want to keep those separated, is to ensure the structure of your `questions` array matches the `items` array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/s7RUfUFcjSnr3L0GajkX?p=preview

We're using a nested ng-repeat, so we must temporarily store the $index of the items array for use in the ng-repeat for `questions`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" data-sec="@{{$index}}" ng-init="itemIndex=$index">
```

next use that variable:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-repeat="question in questions[itemIndex]" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
```

Now the ng-repeats are at least looking in the right place, but it's not enough because `Add_Question()` and `Remove_Question()` don't know about this new data structure. Here's how to update them:

```
<button ng-click="Add_Question(itemIndex)" class="btn btn-success">Agregar Pregunta</button>
```

and

```
<span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="Remove_Question($index, itemIndex)">
```

and finally the JS side:

```
$scope.questions = {};

$scope.Add_Question = function(itemIndex) {
  if($scope.questions[itemIndex] === undefined){
    $scope.questions[itemIndex] = [];
  }
  $scope.questions[itemIndex].push({

  });
};

$scope.Remove_Question = function(index, itemIndex) {
  $scope.questions[itemIndex].splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the item index, $parent can be used directly

Comment: That is true, but I wouldn't do it like that because it's a brittle relationship. Re-arranging the HTML, or adding any directive that creates another $scope could easily break that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your questions array is in the controller scope, and any changes to the collection will reflect to all the child scopes. One option is to keep the questions collection as part of your items object, and make updates to each individual questions collection on add/remove,

```
 $scope.Add_Section = function() {
    $scope.items.push({questions:[]});
  };
```

And

```
 <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="question in item.questions" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
```

Now since questions become a nested collection, removing questions become a little tricky, you need both items' and questions' index to remove. `$parent` comes in handy here to get the items' index

```
$scope.Remove_Question = function(parentIndex,index) {
    $scope.items[parentIndex].questions.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

and

```
<span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="Remove_Question($parent.$index,$index)">
```

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vPmppC)